# Using Now() as a default for MySql DateTime type

Tags: mysql, datetime

How can I setup a MySql schema with a DateTime column such that its value will always be the time of the last insert/update to this row?

Answer (score 8):

You can the TIMESTAMP instead and set the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
lastUpdate TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
);
```

Comment: I did already and voted you up. I also tried to leave the comment 'Well spotted' but it didn't exceed the minimum 15 characters required.

Comment: I hate the 15 characters rule.

Answer (score 4):

Anax was close, but missed the default value.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Anax said, using `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` will give you a column that uses the current time instead of waiting for a provided date/time.

You have a lot of [options with `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html), the two that are most important are:

- Having it use the current time ( `NOW()` ) when the row is created,
- Having it modify the column to the current time when the row is modified.

If you don't set any options, like so:

```
 CREATE TABLE stuff (ts TIMESTAMP);
```

It will put in the current time on creation and *change* that column on modification.

So if you want a column that only shows when it was created, you would use:

```
 CREATE TABLE stuff (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Since you have not specified an `ON UPDATE` clause, it will not do anything if the row is updated.

If you are insane, like me, you'll want both, and go with:

```
 CREATE TABLE stuff (create_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     mod_date TIMESTAMP
                    );
```

and since I haven't written this out yet, that last one is equivalent to writing out:

```
 CREATE TABLE stuff (create_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     mod_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    );
```

Comment: The second last statement really helps me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET NEW.update_date = NOW();
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET NEW.update_date = NOW();
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```